# Snark has been eliminated in chat

Tags: discussion

We have finally achieved a snark-free chat in the watercooler and soon hope to see a great influx of users who were put off by snark in the past.

This achievement could not have come about without recent events and the help of those who took an interest in making this happen.  Some had previously spent little time here, others had been on extended leave.  The end result, however is unquestionable.  Snark has been reduced to nothing, or nearly so.

While we have yet to see the promised engagement of those who helped to bring this about, I am certain that we will see the success that other places who have employed the same strategies have experienced.

It is my sincerest hope that those who helped bring this change about, get to enjoy it to it's fullest.  So please, come to our new improved chat at the watercooler and see what you've been missing.

Answer (score 3):

The reality is it's still the *same ole water cooler* with the removal of the tolerance of allowing folks to misbehave.

There will likely always be a light does of snark, *as it introduces a bit of humor*, but we cannot just be mean and assume the water cooler is our own individual sounding board.

The water cooler belongs to the community as a whole, but if it loses its ability to have fun, well frankly it will end up a **shell of its former self**.

Comment: I don't recall any meanness, just sarcasm and oddball humor.  But agreed, no blowing off steam, and people will leave.